# Crystal distorted wave

Tags: oscillator, crystal

I am using ECS-250-18-30B-JTN-TR crystal with two C0G/NP0 18pF capacitors as loading caps. The crystal is used with WIZnet W5500 chip. When I observe the shape of the sine wave coming in and out of the crystal, the signal on the output looks pretty good.

[image]

However on the input it has some weird shape.

[image]

How can I improve the shape of the waveform? And will it affect the operation of the chip?

This is measure with a x10 probe and the ground pin as short as possible.

Comment: Scope probing might be a serious issue here. You might be trying to fix something that doesn't actually exist.

Comment: Probe loads the crystal. Also probe's bandwidth, impedance (e.g. 1M || 15pF) and division ratio (1x, 10x etc) matter.

Comment: A counter question, how do you know that the waveform needs improving, how do you know if that's how it is supposed to look?

Comment: I read that x10 has lower impedance and I did use x10 to do the measurements. Also, the waveform on one side looks like a perfect sinusoidal wave; therefore I think it is safe to assume that the probing do not have a significant impact on the wave and I should see the same for the other side.

Comment: @Justme honestly I don’t. I am still learning electronics and this is my first implementation of crystal.

Comment: Are your photos properly referenced?... 1st photo: (**XTAL_output**, pin #31), 2nd photo: (**XTAL_input**, pin 30)

Comment: @glen_geek with reference to the IC’s pins, 1st photo - pin 30, 2nd photo - pin 31

Comment: Be aware of Andy & Rohat's cautions - measuring with 'scope alters shape and amplitude of waveforms of these crystal oscillators while the probe is probing. Your waveshapes look reasonable to me, generally of expected shape and amplitude at these pins. The crystal might be somewhat over-driven, but this is generally safer than being under-driven, in which case the oscillation stops.

Comment: what do you mean by overdriving the crystal? do you mean the IC is giving out too much current? In that case should I have a small resistor in series with the XTAL_output pin?

Comment: Yes, a series resistor between output pin (#31) and crystal. App note https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/sces469e/sces469e.pdf section 10.2.3.1 shows 25MHz waveforms with various series resistors. Hard to tell from your waveforms if the xtal is overdriven. Over-driven crystals can do some strange tricks which may not even be noticed - a too-weak oscillator that doesn't start is **very** noticeable!

Answer (score 1):

The load capacitance of your crystal specifies 18 pF but your circuit is probably more like 12 pF if you're using 18 pF capacitors. To achieve 18 pF load capacitance, you have to use ~30 pF capacitors. You can have a look at the article below for more information.

https://www.iqdfrequencyproducts.com/blog/2020/08/03/myths-around-load-capacitance-how-to-choose-the-right-capacitors/